# Customize Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Rating

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, silverlight-4.0

I need to customize the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Rating control. Below code creates a template a bit closer but i need to change icons.

```
<Style x:Key="RatingStyle" TargetType="toolkit:Rating">
    <Setter Property="AllowHalfItemIncrement" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="FilledItemStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="toolkit:RatingItem">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#FF9900" />
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="UnfilledItemStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="toolkit:RatingItem">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#E0E0E0" />
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My required templates are 2, 1 for place rating and one for average price level (shown by $ sign). below is the image showing my requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the quickest method is to change the `Template` of the two styles to adjust the image/look:

```
<Style x:Name="UnfilledDollarStyle" TargetType="toolkit:RatingItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">                
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:RatingItem">
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Foreground="Silver">$</TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
<Style x:Name="FilledDollarStyle" TargetType="toolkit:RatingItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">                
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:RatingItem">
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Foreground="Green">$</TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In use:

```
<toolkit:Rating UnfilledItemStyle="{StaticResource UnfilledDollarStyle}" 
                FilledItemStyle="{StaticResource FilledDollarStyle}" Value="2" />
```

[image: Show me the money (symbols that is)]

By editing the `Template`, you could use images or whatever you'd like within each `RatingItem`.

Of course, you could leave the unfilled style "empty" or completely transparent so that no symbols are shown at all. (To keep consistent spacing around the control, I'd suggest using a fully transparent symbol rather than no content). Here, I've set the `Opacity` to `0`:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="30" Opacity="0">$</TextBlock>
```

[image: Hide symbols, no gray]

Comment: Awesome, i was in fact searching for editing templates and it removed all my pains. Please let me know if i can use style within styles? means you created two different styles and them we directly assign it to control. I created an AveragePriceTemplate and assigned its filled and unfilled to staticrecources. Can we put the two filled/unfilled styles directly in our AveragePriceTemplate without defining their names?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that by directly assigning the style property inline. Although, I'm not 100% sure I understand your question.